# Compare two CSV files and find common then copy both file values in new file

Tags: python, csv

I have no experience in Python. This is my first time to working with Python as well as CSV.

**Problem Statement Details**

I have two CSV files which includes two columns (Person and Balance) as given below

**fileA.csv**

```
Person Balance
 ABC     100
 EFG     90
```

**fileB.csv**

```
Person Balance
 EFG     30
 UVW     400
 ABC     50
```

Compare fileA data to fileB and if Person **ABC** exists in both files (fileA and fileB) then get Person ABC Name and Balance from both files and put into new file. Below is final output I expected.

**DesiredResult.csv**

```
Person Balance Person Balance
 ABC     100    ABC    50
 EFG     90     EFG    30
```

Any code example would be great.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a broad question. Please share the code from your latest attempt(s) so we can take the time to explain the bits where you got stuck. See also [mcve].

Comment: This sounds like homework.  Surely you were given some instruction on the basics of Python and CSV files?

Comment: I would use the Linux `comm` utility, unless it's required to use Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO. To do this you might use the merge method of the Pandas library. Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('fileA.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('fileB.csv')

df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on='Person')

df3.to_csv('DesiredResult.csv')
```

Tell me if it works for you and if you need further explanation.

Comment: Thanks Lorefice. Thanks for the help. Should I create DesiredResult.csv in my desired folder or df3.to_csv('DesiredResult.csv') command will create it automatically?

Comment: The 'to_csv' method creates the file in your working directory. If the answer was usefull upvote it please.