CHEMBL database related query- dual targets
Is there a way to download a list of compounds with dual targets from CHEMBL. for example :I can download a list of compounds with estrogen receptor activity separately and a list of  NMDA antagonist separately. Is there a way to create and download a list of compounds with activity against both. Only other way i can think of is manually curating the. Thanks

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you mean https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/ ? If so, then it would help if you could edit that information into your question. Most Stack Overflow users probably aren't experts in biochemistry, but if you can show examples of the two datasets that you want to merge, and what the result of the merge should look like, then we can suggest ways of merging them after downloading them (or you never know, there might be a way of getting the API to merge them before downloading the result). But without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, and with what, we can't be sure.

Thanks for reaching out. I apologize for my lack of knowledge and inadequate information. Yes you have the right CHEMBL from which i am able to extract my 2 csv files. The best example I can find is this question                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103724/compare-two-csv-files-and-find-common-then-copy-both-file-values-in-new-file                                                                 I can merge the files but i am not sure how to delete the values that are not common. How do I delete the person UVW from my merged data. My merged data has almost 1000 rows.

One approach which suggests itself to me is to import each dataset into its own table in a database and then run a query using an inner join to return just the rows where the same value appears in both tables. Another is to import both datasets into a spreadsheet application such as Excel, use the vlookup function to merge the two, and then filter the results to omit rows which are in one dataset but not the other.

The best solution for your use case is going to depend a lot on what software / programming languages / other tools are available to you, your level of experience in using them, and whether you want to perform this process as a one-off or you want to be able to run it repeatedly each time the source data is updated. If you can edit this information into your question, along with the code you've already tried and how its results differ from what you want, it will greatly improve the chances of getting an answer.
